# Fetch text string from specific column and select range of that string and edit value

Tags: google-apps-script

I have shared my sheet below.

I would like to match text from column A and return or getValue of corresponding B column.

So I can use that getValue from its corresponding B column for further arithmetic operations.

I have tried below code. in which i have able to achieve getValued of column B but not able to go further.

My desired outputs are commented in code.

Sheet link = https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/16Ox2h2CJKkMW59SFn8SPitUmNmURYSo9_HNoHrKuEmQ/edit#gid=578595593

```
function myFunction() {
var sheet=SpreadsheetApp.openById('16Ox2h2CJKkMW59SFn8SPitUmNmURYSo9_HNoHrKuEmQ').getSheetByName('Summary');
var sheet2 = SpreadsheetApp.openById('16Ox2h2CJKkMW59SFn8SPitUmNmURYSo9_HNoHrKuEmQ').getSheetByName('Updates');

var lastrow = sheet2.getLastRow();
var lastcolumn = sheet2.getLastColumn();

var type = sheet2.getRange(lastrow, 2).getValue();
var addv = sheet2.getRange(lastrow, 3).getValue();

var a =type;
var b =addv;

var matchText = type;
var values = SpreadsheetApp.openById('16Ox2h2CJKkMW59SFn8SPitUmNmURYSo9_HNoHrKuEmQ').getSheetByName('Summary').getDataRange().getValues();
var columnA =values.map(function(e){return e[0]});  
var row = columnA.indexOf(matchText);
var Bvalue = values[row][1];


Logger.log(Bvalue);


//here i want to write condition to add

if(row >= 0){

 //here i want if condition matched i would like to var addv in var Bvalue

}

else {

//here i would like to append new row where in column A var type will get appended and in corresponding B column var addv get appended

}


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want to do the following:

- Retrieve information from the last row in sheet `Updates` (columns B and C). Variables `type` and `addv`.
- Look for values in column A from `Summary` that match the retrieved `type`.
- If a match is found, update column B of corresponding row in `Summary`, adding `addv` to the previously existing number.
- If a match is not found, append a new row to `Summary`, with `type` and `addv`.

If this is correct, you could do the following:

```js
function myFunction() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sheet1 = ss.getSheetByName("Summary");
  var sheet2 = ss.getSheetByName("Updates");
  var type = sheet2.getRange(sheet2.getLastRow(), 2).getValue();
  var addv = sheet2.getRange(sheet2.getLastRow(), 3).getValue();  
  var values = sheet1.getDataRange().getValues();
  var columnA = values.map(function(e){return e[0]});  
  var index = columnA.indexOf(type);
  if (index == -1) { // If match is not found
    sheet1.appendRow([type, addv]); // Append row
  } else { // If match is found
    var rangeToUpdate = sheet1.getRange(index + 1, 2);
    rangeToUpdate.setValue(rangeToUpdate.getValue() + addv); // Add addv to corresponding value in column B
  }
}
```

#### Note:

- Your code had a fair amount of repetition, I minimized it a bit.

#### Reference:

- [appendRow(rowContents)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#appendrowrowcontents)
- [setValue(value)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setvaluevalue)

Comment: @lamblichus thank for your update i rn the script twice it ran well now it gives me error

TypeError: Cannot read property '1' of undefined (line 18, file "Code")

Comment: @patu I tested this before posting, so this is working. Make sure you copy the script exactly as I posted it. I'm not accessing any property '1', so this error can't come from the code I shared. Most probably you didn't delete this line: `var Bvalue = values[row][1];` (I changed the variable name `row` to `index`)